# Comparing Strings compareTo in java

Tags: java, android, string, compareto

I'm trying to check if a string alphabetically fits between two other strings.
At the moment i'm doing it like this:

```
if(_subSize.compareTo("440/65") > 0 && "600/65".compareTo(_subSize) < 0){
    //fits in
} else { // fits not in between }
```

But when I have as _subSize = "440/65"; the if statement gets in the else. I've fixed that like this:

```
if(_subSize.compareTo("440/65") >= 0 && "600/65".compareTo(_subSize) <= 0){
    //fits in
} else { // fits not in between }
```

now the first statement is true. Yet the 2nd statement is false.
How to get the 2nd statement to be true aswell?
as "440/65" alphabetically comes before "600/65" so technically it should be lower or equals to 0. But somehow it's not working.

And i need the strings to be as string. They are no digits or something.

Comment: which is correct alphabetically or alfabetically

Comment: Try using `"600/65".compareTo(_subSize) >= 0` instead. Though I must admit that this is the worst kind of range comparison I've ever seen.

Comment: @R.J I think you gave the correct answer.

Comment: @Tarik - Yeah I knew that, but I didn't feel like posting it as an answer. This is one really bad way of comparison of ranges and I'm not fond of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd .compareTo() is inverted related to the first one.  You just need to have both to compare from the same perspective as follows:

```
if(_subSize.compareTo("440/65") >= 0 && _subSize.compareTo("600/65") <= 0){
    //fits in
} else { // fits not in between }
```